# custom widget with aspect ratio (GTK2+)

Tags: gtk

I'm currently writing my own GTK2-Widget derived from GtkWidget and I want it to keep a certain aspect ratio, just like GtkAspectFrame does, but I have no idea how to do this. For example, if GTK+ offers my widget a width of 400px, I want it to have a height of 400px, 200px, etc (depending on the ratio). To set a simple size request isn't the solution, because my widget's size depends on the size of other widgets.

Comment: Don't take this, wrong, but gtk3 has inbuilt aspect/ratio support. So if you can switch, that might be an easier option. If not, then I'd suggest to emit a signal in another widget, catch that in your widget implementation and do a size request right there (maybe explicitly queue a draw). (Note - this was just a quick idea)